# Can't connect to sites after disconnecting from intranet

Tags: 17.10, dns

After upgrading to Kubuntu 17.10 I have the following issue:

After reboot, connecting to internet sites works as normal.

Then, I connected to an intranet of the domain somedomain.com. Still, everything works.

Then, after disconnecting from the intranet, all sites of the domain somedomain.com stopped working, although they are publicly accessible on the internet. Also, `ssh` and `ping` couldn't connect from the terminal. I got the message:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname somedomain.com: Name or service not known
```

Only rebooting would fix this.

After some searching around, I found that `/etc/resolv.conf` and some other related resolv files still contained

```
search somedomain.com
```

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of searching I found this [bug report](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/6572), which is probably unrelated, but had the useful information right at the end of the thread:

> You're correct. I removed resolvconf and the problem resolved. Systemd seems to be doing it right. This seems to be a remnant from a buggy release upgrade. Apologies for polluting the thread.

So, for everyone having the same issue, just do

```
sudo apt remove resolvconf
```